# Background: url does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image

I have a menu with 2 background images with hover.
The problem is that I don't see the images background in Firefox.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="markermenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a  href="#" id="one">Moda e Accessori</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" id="two">Hotel e Viaggi</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" id="three">Cosmesi</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" id="four">Giochi e Scommesse</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" id="five">Elettronica</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS, for example for the first voice:

```css
.markermenu{
 width: 311px; /*width of menu*/
}

.markermenu ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 1px 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0px solid #9A9A9A;
}

.markermenu ul li a#one{    
 background: url(/img/icon/moda.png) 20px, url(/img/icon/arrow.png) 280px, -webkit-  gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#EBF0EF)) ;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-color:#fff;
 height:79px;
 color: #17548e;
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 padding: 30px 0;
 padding-left: 90px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D4DBD9;
 border-left: 1px solid #D4DBD9;
}

.markermenu ul li a#one:hover{
 color: #fff;
 background:url(img/icon/giac.png) 20px, url(img/icon/arrow_white.png) 280px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-color: #17548e;
 /*onMouseover image change. Remove if none*/
}
```

All good in Chrome but in Firefox I don't see the images, I show the image only with the hover.

Someone know why?

Comment: make sure the path of css file and images are correct; use single quotation for images path maybe works

Comment: Wait...is this a FF issue (first line)...or Safari issue (penultimate line).

Comment: Is there a reason why your `-webkit-gradient` is broken into `-webkit- gradient`

Comment: FF! sorry. and i have the latest version of FF

Comment: -webkit- gradient  i have correct this but is not that the broblem

Comment: We need a jsfiddle to properly debug this with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.markermenu ul li #one {
  background: url(/img/icon/moda.png), url(/img/icon/arrow.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #EBF0EF);
  background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 0, 280px 0; /* if these positions are incorrect plz correct them */
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yep, it's the -webkit-gradient that FF is not happy about.

Comment: mh No, the position is correct and run in Crhome...if i write:

background:url(img/icon/moda.png) 20px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#EBF0EF)) ;
background:url(img/icon/arrow.png) 280px; 

...i see only the arrow...

Comment: As you know webkit-gradient is for Chrome and Safary but if you want to use same for FF you need to change it to `linear-gradient`

Comment: with your code i see the gradient in crhome and FF but i dont see the images...:(

Comment: Which browser does it show the images and gradient background? Maybe the images position are not correct or maybe the images path are not correct

Comment: Crhome does images and gradient! :D